# What does "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "silk_request" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO "silk_reque mean?

Tags: python, django, django-models

So, here is what I have done. I have cloned this repo https://github.com/hitul007/complianceok
followed by `git stash` then
`git checkout due_date` and
`git pull origin due_date`

when i tried to run the server, it throws an error which i couldnt understand. Not only that, I could not even locate the file where this actual problem is?

What is this silk thing?

Can someone please explain what is the actual issue and how do I solve it?  I am using python 3.8 and django 3.1.2[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdM6W.png)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The link that you have provided doesn't work (404 error).

This "silk" error probably generated by `django-silk` package. Guess that if this name doesn't anything to you, the easiest solution for you would be removing it from dependencies (`Pipfile` or `requirements.txt`).

P.S. `django-silk` package is a profiling tool for django.

Answer (score 1):

Run the migrations for django-silk:

```
/manage.py makemigrations silk

Migrations for 'silk':
  venv_3_9_10/lib/python3.9/site-packages/silk/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Request
    - Create model SQLQuery
    - Create model Response
    - Create model Profile


./manage.py migrate silk
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error,I solve it by `python manage.py migrate`